# Seekbar thumb control from right end

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I am using a wider drawable as seekbar thumb. 
When i drag the thumb, the thumb image moves with its 'pivot' at the centre. Is it possible to consider the right edge of the image as the pivot instead?

Comment: initial progress = 100, set/read progress (100-x)

Comment: I think you got me wrong. I don't want the progress from right to left. I have a very wide drawable. Like this. http://postimg.org/image/p6wjoti21/ . I want to be able to drag from the right end. That is the hand in this case. Because initially I set a heavy offset for it to align to the beginning. Then when I move right my image goes way ahead of my thumb.

Comment: I understand now.. Its a good question. A quick and dirty way would be to create the image with empty/transparent space on the right half.

Comment: Already tried a transparent png. Doesn't work. Still blocks the seekbar. Any ideas?

Comment: I did it by making a double width transparent png and set splittrack=false. It works well. Just one issue, when my finger is pressed down to drag a shadow forms around the drawable. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A quick and dirty way would be to create the image with empty/transparent space on the right half. ( On API 21 and above - also add the `splittrack=false` property on the seekbar or the thumb image will not be transparent)
- On API 21 and above a ripple effect would appear on touch, by default. You can disable it by using a selector for `android:thumb` property of the seekbar. This selector must have the same drawable for focused/selected/normal states(This drawable could be null)

Comment: Thanks. The first way works. For the second. android:background="@null" also works. Thanks a lot.